# $\operatorname{Hom}(C,R) \otimes G \simeq\operatorname{Hom}(C,G)$

Tags: homological-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, group-homomorphism, bilinear-form

Given $C,G$ free $R-$modules, I was interesed in proving that $\operatorname{Hom}C,R) \otimes G \simeq\operatorname{Hom}(C,G)$ if $G$ is finitely generated.

I thought $\psi : \varphi \otimes g \longmapsto \varphi \cdot g$ could be the isomorphism I was looking for but I wasn't sure about the inverse, I didn't came up with a direct proof of an isomorphism.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

**Edit :** FiMePr answer was given before adding the word $free$ to the question.

Comment: If the question below answers a previous version of this post please do not edit it in a way that makes the answer look like it’s addressing another question. Instead, edit the post to clearly reflect the changes you made to the original question the answer below addressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the result is false if you don't add more hypotheses :

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $C = G = \mathbb{Z}/2$.

Then $Hom(C, R) = Hom(\mathbb{Z}/2, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$, so $Hom(C, R) \otimes G = 0$

but $Hom(C,G) = Hom(\mathbb{Z}/2, \mathbb{Z}/2) = \mathbb{Z}/2$.

However, the result is true if $C,G$ are free and finitely generated, i.e., if both of them are isomorphic to some $R^n$, for $n$ an integer (not necessarily the same integer for $C$ and $G$).

EDIT : With the edited hypotheses :

$Hom(\oplus_{i \in I} R, R) \otimes R^n = (\prod_{i \in I} Hom(R,R))\otimes R^n = R^I \otimes R^n = \oplus_{k=1}^n R^I \otimes R = R^{n \times I} = \prod_{i \in I} Hom(R, R^n) = Hom(\oplus_{i \in I} R, R^n)$.

EDIT^2 : If we only assume $G$ to be free and finitely generated :

$Hom(C,G) = Hom(C, R^n) = Hom(C,R)^n = \oplus_{i=1}^n Hom(C, R) = (\oplus_{i=1}^n Hom(C, R))\otimes R  = \oplus_{i=1}^n (Hom(C, R)\otimes R) =  Hom(C, R)\otimes (\oplus_{i=1}^n R) = Hom(C, R) \otimes R^n = Hom(C,R) \otimes G$.

Comment: You're right I forgot to add C,G to be free, I'm gonna edit the post

Comment: Is it enough to ask $C$ free and $G$ finitely generated right ?

Comment: @jacopoburelli Not so sure about that. The tensor product does not commute with infinite cartesian products in general.

Comment: I found the result at p.297 of Tammo Tom Dieck "Algebraic Topology" without a proof of the fact, from there the question arises. So I was curios about the fact, but I can't find a proof

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot. It works as you say

Comment: Still not seeing entirely why, if you want to expand your question, would be appreciated.

Comment: @jacopoburelli Edited. The computation seems to work.

Comment: If G is finitely generated free this works for any C. Just write G as R^d and use standard properties of hom and tensor to get both sides are Hom(C,R)^d